# Karate - Conditional if and contains when response can be either json or html

Tags: html, json, if-statement, contains, karate

I am making a request where the response can either be returned as a Json or HTML.

I am trying to write a condition based on the html case, in which if the response contains the string 'my string', then call another feature file. I have tried reading the documentation on [conditional logic](https://github.com/intuit/karate#conditional-logic), and [contains](https://github.com/intuit/karate#match-contains), however, I am still having trouble.

Here are the steps I'm taking:

```
Given url 'someUrl'
When method get
Then status 200
```

**# The response can return a json object similar to this:**

```
* def jsonResponse=
"""
{
  "del_date_range": "new Object",
  "twoday_date": null,
  "sameday": null,
  "calendar_end_day": 23,
  "zip_error_message_id": null
}
"""
```

**# The response can return this HTML:**

```
* def htmlResponse=
"""
<span class="text">
    <p>my string</p>
</span>
"""
```

**# Now I want to create an if condition that says if the response contains the string 'my string', then call another feature file.**

**I want to do something like this, but this does not work:**

```
 * if (response contains 'my string') karate.call('calledFeature.feature')
```

I will get an error like this:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: <eval>:1:13 Expected ) but found contains
```

**What is the best way to achieve this? If the Json object is returned -> do nothing. If the html is returned -> call the other feature file.** Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
* string temp = response
* def isHtml = temp.startsWith('<')
```

Now you can do any kind of conditional calls you want.